# Is there a way to configure magento search to show a particular block if no search results are returned?

Tags: magento-1.9, products, search

Is there a way to configure magento search to show a particular block in the search result area if no results are returned. For example may be I can show the recently view items or most popular items.

Answer (score 3):

There is an extension available that gives you an xml handle for empty search results page - https://github.com/drewhunter/EmptyHandles

If you install that you will be able to do the following to display recently viewed products on the empty search result page.

This example I have done on my local Magento RWD theme, its unsetting the recently viewed block already visible in the right hand side bar and placing it in the main content.

```
    <catalogsearch_result_index_empty>
        <reference name="right">
      <action method="unsetChild"><name>right.reports.product.viewed</name></action>
   </reference>     
        <reference name="content">
      <action method="insert">
        <block>right.reports.product.viewed</block>
    </action>
   </reference>
    </catalogsearch_result_index_empty>
```

If the recently viewed block isnt already there in your theme you can add as easy as

```
    <catalogsearch_result_index_empty>
        <reference name="content">
      <block type="reports/product_viewed" before="right.permanent.callout" name="right.reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />
   </reference>
    </catalogsearch_result_index_empty>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Bobadevv for your comment. I downloaded the extension and I wanted to use the blocks from my the Back-end > CMS > Block. To do so, I changed the code in app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/emptyhandles.xml to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<layout>
    <catalog_category_view_empty>
        <!-- Layout code here to control empty category pages -->
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="cms/block" name="block_empty_search2">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_empty_search</block_id></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_view_empty>
    <catalogsearch_result_index_empty>
        <!-- Layout code here to control empty search result pages -->
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="cms/block" name="block_empty_search2">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_empty_search</block_id></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_result_index_empty>
    <checkout_cart_index_empty>
        <!-- Layout code here to control empty cart pages -->
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="cms/block" name="block_empty_search2">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_empty_search</block_id></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index_empty>
</layout>
```

I hope it helps someone else. Cheers.